# Refresh token with Google API via Flask-Dance

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm having hard times implementing Google OAuth with Flask-Dance. Here is the deal. In order to make everything work I need to set `offline=True`
and `reprompt_consent=True` when creating Google blueprint:

```
google_bp = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id="trololo",
    client_secret="ololo",
    offline=True,
    reprompt_consent=True,
    scope=["email"],
    redirect_url="/callback/google"
)
```

However `reprompt_consent=True` naturally makes the app reprompt user for offline access every time user logs in.

Any other combination of these 2 parameters results in missing `refresh_token` for `Oauth2lib`.

I don't need the offline access per se, but as I figured, it seems the only way to escape that missing parameter error. So is there any other way to log in with Google via Flask-Dance and get that `refresh_token` passed around?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in flask dance for google you'll need to implement a `Backend` in order to store anything from the OAuth Dance. Here's a snippet from the docs to get you started.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_dance.consumer.backend.sqla import OAuthConsumerMixin, SQLAlchemyBackend

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ... other columns as needed

class OAuth(OAuthConsumerMixin, db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User)

blueprint.backend = SQLAlchemyBackend(OAuth, db.session, user=current_user)
```

In the example above, you can now query the SQL db for the user.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'm not sure how the snippet above relates to the stated problem. Naturally I do have a DB in my app, but the question was how to login without reprompting consent

Comment: @mike-tung Do you have any or know of any examples that implements this SQLAlchemyBackend?

Answer (score 0):

For other people looking for an answer: If you have already granted access without the `offline=True` setting, you must go to your Google account and revoke access to your app before this will work by itself. Otherwise, `reprompt_consent=True` will be needed.